# How to prevent Spyder 5 from lagging, which makes the editor unusable on large files?

Tags: spyder

I installed the latest Spyder on a new Windows machine but I experience a serious lag (few seconds) while typing that makes the editor non functional.

To reproduce the problem:

- Open a large script (I need to edit one that has 3000 lines of code).
- The lag is minimal at first, but as I leave the editor open for several hours it becomes unusable.
- Let say I continuously type random characters for 2 seconds, then pause for 1s, then repeat.
- I will see my typing at first, but at some point the editor will **stall for as much as 4 seconds** and then empty the keyboard buffer on screen before freezing again for 4 seconds.

The following attempts did not help :

- Reducing de size of the Sypder Editor (non full screen)
- Unchecking "Enable code completion and linting in the editor"

The only thing that helps is to restart the Spyder editor every hour or so.

Installed using the command `conda install spyder`

Packages versions:

- spyder 5.0.5
- qt 5.9.7
- pyqt 5.9.2

on Windows 10 Pro 19043.1288

Does anyone have a work around for this problem?

Comment: 1. Do you use `Kite`? if yes, disable this. Kite uses a lot of resources, especially when you have a large script open. 
2. Is the script stored on your local hard disk, or in a shared folder on the network. With the latter one I also experience slows behavior from spyder.

Comment: I did not install Kite

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry for the inconvenience. Most of the problems you mention are fixed in our **5.1.5** version, released last September and already available in Anaconda. More typing enhancements will be available in future versions (we're working on them right now).